# I have a result set of continuous days and a severity rating. I would like to aggregate these into StartDate, EndDate, Severity

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

In SQL Server I have a table with the following data

```
Date        Severity
2018-09-10  40
2018-09-11  40
2018-09-12  40
2018-09-13  40
2018-09-14  40
2018-09-15  40
2018-09-16  20
2018-09-17  20
2018-09-18  20
2018-09-19  30
2018-09-20  30
2018-09-21  30
2018-09-22  30
```

i would like to obtain an aggregate of the dates and the severity

```
Start      End        Severity
2018-09-10 2018-09-15 40
2018-09-16 2018-09-18 20
2018-09-19 2018-09-22 30
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing this is really a gaps-and-islands problem.  If so:

```
select severity, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by severity order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by dateadd(day, - seqnum, date), severity;
```

This will get adjacent rows with the same severity.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table firstly :

```
create table tab(Date date,Severity int);
insert into tab 
select '2018-09-10',40 union all
select '2018-09-11',40 union all
select '2018-09-12',40 union all     
select '2018-09-13',40 union all
select '2018-09-14',40 union all
select '2018-09-15',40 union all
select '2018-09-16',20 union all
select '2018-09-17',20 union all
select '2018-09-18',20 union all     
select '2018-09-19',30 union all
select '2018-09-20',30 union all
select '2018-09-21',30 union all     
select '2018-09-22',30;
```

and then, use :

```
select min(q."Start") as "Start", max(q."End") as "End", q.Severity
  from
    (
    select min(Date) as "Start",       
           max(Date) as "End",
           avg(Severity) as Severity
      from tab
     group by Date, Severity 
    ) q
 group by Severity   
 order by "Start"
```

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/ZRXSQ14415)

Comment: Thank you for this also, this is just as correct as the first answer.  I up voted for providing the rextester Demo!